# Create margin for equal children in parent without overflow

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a gap between two children divs of a parent wrapper. The issue is, I create the widths as a percentage (50), and would like a fixed margin of `10px` total without overflowing the parent.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="one" class="child"> </div>
        <div id="two" class="child"> </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

When I add margins, or padding to "one" or "two", this exceeds the total 100% of the parents width. Can I add the margin/padding to the div element so that it is calculated into the 50% of the parent?

Here is a fiddle illustrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cusyyddx/

Comment: If you know the wrapper is always 600px, couldn't you use pixel values instead of percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `calc` for your width attribute: `width: calc(50% - 1px);`. Works in IE9+

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, now no overflow and 10px gap between both

```
#wrapper {
width: 600px;
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49.15%;
    height: 50px;
}

#one {

    background: purple;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#two {
    background: orange;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```